# Mac Mini Server with Thunderbolt Drive as file share

Tags: mac-osx, network-storage, mac

I am looking at expanding my Mac Mini Server with a LaCie 10TB 5big Thunderbolt Series Hard Drive, I have received mixed messages about whether it is possible to use a Thunderbolt drive to setup network share points on the Mac Mini Server it is plugged in to.

Is it possible to have a Thunderbolt drive shared on the network as a Mac Sharepoint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a recommended solution by Apple, actually. It was one under consideration when I was looking for a way to implement company-wide [Apple laptop backups](https://serverfault.com/questions/575357/backup-strategy-for-developer-focused-apple-environments).

Since thunderbolt is a high-bandwidth interconnect, there are some very interesting [external hardware RAID enclosures](http://eshop.macsales.com/shop/Thunderbolt/#tbexternaldrives) available for it. You can run any of these behind a Mini (Ideally using OS X Server) and share the volume to clients.

Comment: What format are thunderbolt drives in?

Comment: They're presented as block devices to your Mac... so you can format them the same way you would an internal drive. Use HFS+.

Comment: Thanks, I was concerned that spending so much on a device that I would not be able to use it for network share points, I have found reports online that some people found that users couldn't use the share.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is certainly possible. Any directly-connected block storage (USB, Thunderbolt, iSCSI, etc.) can be shared in OSX.